# Slow Javascript code to get Taxonomy terms from Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

We have the following code which takes about 5 seconds in a modern computer, however the application is also executed on old PCs with Windows XP, and in there it takes 5 minutes to load.   I know the old pcs are slow, but 5 minutes its just ridiculous slow, this code was developed by someone else and now we have to improve it.

Any suggestion is welcome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // limpia la localStorage con cambios anteriores
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("limp")==null){
        localStorage.clear();
        sessionStorage.setItem("limp","1");
    }
    var scriptbase = "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js");
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(re, "SP.Runtime.js");
})

function re (){
    $("div[webpartid=608c8fe4-e5db-49de-8550-840b1706ba1c]").hide();
    var scriptbase = "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){

        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js");

    });
    SetFullScreenMode(true);
    PreventDefaultNavigation();
}

var metaFieldName = "SIG"; //Change to your site column names
var lvl; //Handle the different pages
var anterior;
var filterOutput1;
var TaxConfiguration = {

    SspId: "",
    GroupId: "",
    TermSetId: "",
    Configuration: "",
    FieldName: "",
    ParseConfiguration: function () {

        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(this.Configuration);
        xml = $(xmlDoc);

        var fieldDef = xml.find("Field");
        this.FieldName = $(fieldDef).attr("DisplayName");

        var properties = xml.find("Property");

        for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {

            propertyName = properties[i].firstChild.textContent == undefined ? 
                                properties[i].firstChild.text : properties[i].firstChild.textContent;
            propertyValue = properties[i].lastChild.textContent == undefined ?
                                properties[i].lastChild.text : properties[i].lastChild.textContent;

            if (propertyName == propertyValue) {
                propertyValue = "";
            }

            switch (propertyName) {
                case "SspId":
                    this.SspId = propertyValue;
                    break;
                case "GroupId":
                    this.GroupId = propertyValue;
                    break;
                case "TermSetId":
                    this.TermSetId = propertyValue;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function maxiFilter() {
    if ($("#maxFilter").html()==' - Ocultar elementos') {
        $("#maxFilter").html(" + Ver elementos");
    } else {
        $("#maxFilter").html(" - Ocultar elementos");
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('lvl')==2){
        $("#start").slideToggle();
    }else {
        $("#filter").slideToggle();
    }
}

function seeBread () {
    var bread = sessionStorage.getItem("bread");
    if (bread != null){
        var breadElements = bread.split("...");
        var output = "";
        var content;
        for(i=0;i<breadElements.length-1;i++)
        {
            content = '"' + breadElements[i].split(",")[1] + '"';
            if (breadElements[i].split(",")[1] == "final") {
                output += "<p class='separator'> > </p><span id='final' onclick='irAtrasBread(" + content + ", true)'>" + breadElements[i].split(",")[0] + "</span>";
            }else {
                output += "<p class='separator'> > </p><a onclick='irAtrasBread(" + content + ", true)'>" + breadElements[i].split(",")[0] + "</a>";
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        output = '';
    }
    var start = "'" + 'start' + "'";
    $("#bread").html('<p class="separator"> > </p><a href="#" onclick="irAtrasBread('+start + ',true)">Mapa de procesos</a>' + output);
}

function irAtras () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")=="3") {
        backToStart();
    }else{
        var a = $("#0").attr("data-anterior");
        var txtHtml = sessionStorage.getItem(a);
        mostrarAtras(txtHtml);
        irAtrasBread(a, false);
    }   
}

function backToStart () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")=="3") {
        $("#filter").hide();
        $("#maxFilter").hide();
        $("#bread").hide();
        $("#atras").hide();
        $("#start").html(sessionStorage.getItem("start"));
        $("#start").show();
        sessionStorage.setItem("lvl", 2);
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", "start");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("bread");
    }
}

function irAtrasBread (cookieName, direct){
    $("#maxFilter").hide();
    $("#maxFilter").html(" - Ocultar elementos");
    $("div[webpartid=608c8fe4-e5db-49de-8550-840b1706ba1c]").hide();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")=="3" && direct == true) {
        backToStart();
    }else{
        var cookie = sessionStorage.getItem("bread");
        var breadElements = cookie.split("...");
        var bread = "";
        var state = 0;
        for(i=0;i<breadElements.length-1;i++)
        {
            if(breadElements[i].split(",")[1] != cookieName){
                bread += breadElements[i].split(",")[0] + "," + breadElements[i].split(",")[1] + "...";
            } else {
                state = i;
                i = breadElements.length;
            }
        }
        var stateLVL = (breadElements.length-1)-state;
        if(direct&&cookieName!="final"){
            setLvl(stateLVL, "restar");
            if(lvl==2){
                $("#atras").hide();
            }
        }
        if (cookieName!="final") {
            sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", cookieName);  
            var cookieValue = sessionStorage.getItem(cookieName);
            if (lvl == 2) {
                $("#filter").hide();
                $("#bread").hide();
                $("#start").html(cookieValue);
                $("#start").show();

            }else{
                seeBread();
                $("#bread").show();
                $("#start").hide();
                $("#filter").html(cookieValue); 
                $("#filter").show();
            }
        };

        sessionStorage.setItem("bread", bread);

    }
}

function setLvl (num, task) {
    lvl = sessionStorage.getItem("lvl");
    if (task == "restar"){
        lvl = lvl - num;
    }else if (task == "sumar"){
        lvl = parseInt(lvl) + num;
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("lvl", lvl);
}

function mostrarAtras (txtHtml) {
    $("#filter").html(txtHtml);
    setLvl(1, "restar");
    if (lvl == 1) {
        $("#atras").hide(); 
    }
    $("div[webpartid=608c8fe4-e5db-49de-8550-840b1706ba1c]").hide();
}

function GetTermsRecursive(sspId, termSetId){
    var terms = new Array();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SspId", taxconfig.SspId);
    sessionStorage.setItem("TermSetId", taxconfig.TermSetId);
    sessionStorage.setItem("FieldName", taxconfig.FieldName);
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetChildTermsInTermSet",
        async: false,
        sspId: sspId,
        termSetId: termSetId,
        lcid: 1033,
        completefunc: GetDataInit
        });
}

function GetChildTerms(sspId, termSetId, roottermId, termName){
    setLvl(1,"sumar");
    $("#bread").show();
    GetChildTermsRecursive(sspId, termSetId, roottermId, termName);
}

function GetChildTermsRecursive(sspId, termSetId, roottermId, termName){
    var cookie = sessionStorage.getItem(cookieName);
    var aux = sessionStorage.getItem("bread");
    $("#filter").show();
    lvl = sessionStorage.getItem("lvl");
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")>3) {
        var cookieName = "lvl" + lvl + "_" + roottermId;
        var a = document.getElementById('0');
        anterior = a.getAttribute("data-lvl");
        $("#start").hide();
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", cookieName);
    } else if (sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")==3){
        sessionStorage.setItem("bread", termName + ",start...");
        $("#start").hide();
    }
    $("div[webpartid=608c8fe4-e5db-49de-8550-840b1706ba1c]").hide();
    if(cookie != undefined){
        var aux = sessionStorage.getItem("bread");
        $("#filter").html(cookie);
        $("#atras").show();
    } else {
        var terms = new Array();
        $("#filter").html('');
        $("#loadingOptions").show();
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetChildTermsInTerm",
            async: false,
            sspId: sspId,
            termId: roottermId,
            termSetId: termSetId,
            lcid: 1033,
            completefunc: GetData
            });
        if (lvl > "3") {
            a = document.getElementById('0');
            var actual = a.getAttribute("data-lvl");
        }
    }
    if (lvl > "3") {
        sessionStorage.setItem("bread", aux + termName + "," + anterior + "...");
    }
    seeBread();
    return terms;    
}

function GetDataInit(xData, Status) 
{
    if(Status == "success")
    {
        terms = new Array();
        xmlData = xData;        
        // Fix for different XML parsing in IE and Chrome
        termsContent = $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).firstChild.textContent == undefined ?
                            $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).text : 
                            $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).firstChild.textContent;
        termsXML = $.parseXML(termsContent);
        $termsXML = $(termsXML);
        var childTerms = $termsXML.find("T");
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            termName = $(childTerms[j]).find("TL");
            hasChildTermsXml = $(childTerms[j]).find("TM");

            // request if child terms are avaliable
            hasChildTerms = $(hasChildTermsXml).attr("a69");

            var tsTerm = new Object();

            // Requesting actual term id
            tsTerm.termId = $(childTerms[j]).attr("a9");

            // Requestion term value ID
            tsTerm.valueID = $(childTerms[j]).attr("a1000");
            // Requesting term name
            tsTerm.termName = termName.attr("a32");

            sessionStorage.setItem("cat", tsTerm.termId);
            //sessionStorage.setItem("lvl",2);
            GetChildTermsRecursive(sessionStorage.getItem("SspId"), sessionStorage.getItem("TermSetId"), tsTerm.termId, tsTerm.termName);
            //sessionStorage.setItem("lvl",2);
            sessionStorage.setItem("start", $("#start").html());
            sessionStorage.setItem("start", $("#start").html());
            sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", "start");
        }

    }
}


function GetData(xData, Status) 
{
    if(Status == "success")
    {
        var hasParent = 0;
        var cons = 0;
        var filterOutput = "";

        terms = new Array();
        xmlData = xData;        
        // Fix for different XML parsing in IE and Chrome
        termsContent = $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).firstChild.textContent == undefined ?
                            $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).text : 
                            $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText).firstChild.textContent;
        termsXML = $.parseXML(termsContent);
        $termsXML = $(termsXML);
        var childTerms = $termsXML.find("T");
        parentTermId = null;
        GUID = null;

        lvl = sessionStorage.getItem("lvl");
        $("#loadingOptions").hide();
        $("#mensaje").show();
        for(i = 0; i < childTerms.length; i++)
        {

            termName = $(childTerms[i]).find("TL");
            hasChildTermsXml = $(childTerms[i]).find("TM");

            // request if child terms are avaliable
            hasChildTerms = $(hasChildTermsXml).attr("a69");

            var tsTerm = new Object();

            // Requesting actual term id
            tsTerm.termId = $(childTerms[i]).attr("a9");

            // Requestion term value ID
            tsTerm.valueID = $(childTerms[i]).attr("a1000");
            // Requesting term name
            tsTerm.termName = termName.attr("a32");

            // Setting Parent Term ID
            parentTermId = $(hasChildTermsXml).attr("a25");
            if (GUID == null){
                GUID = parentTermId;    
            }

            if (parentTermId != undefined) {
                hasParent = parentTermId;   
            }

            var sspId = '"'+sessionStorage.getItem("SspId")+'"';
            var termSetId = '"'+sessionStorage.getItem("TermSetId")+'"';
            var termId = '"'+tsTerm.termId+'"';
            var currentPage = $(location).attr('href').split("?")[0];
            var termName1 = '"' + tsTerm.termName + '"';
            var sumar = "sumar";
            var GUID1 = '"'+GUID+'"';
            if (hasChildTerms == "true"){
                filterOutput += "<a id='" + cons + "' data-lvl='lvl" + lvl + "_" + GUID +"' data-anterior='" + anterior + "' onclick='GetChildTerms(" + sspId + "," + termSetId + "," + termId + "," + termName1 + ")'><div class='text'><p>"+
                    tsTerm.termName+"</p></div></a>";               
            } else {
                filterOutput += "<a id='" + cons + "' onclick='setBread(" + termName1 + "," + lvl + "," + GUID1 + ")' data-lvl='lvl" + lvl + "_" + GUID +"' data-anterior='" + anterior + "' href='" + currentPage + "?FilterField1=" + sessionStorage.getItem("FieldName") + "&FilterValue1=" + tsTerm.valueID + "&FilterLookupId1=1'><div class='text'><p>"+tsTerm.termName+"</p></div></a>";
            }   

            terms[i] = tsTerm;
            cons++;
        }
        //onclick='alert(" + '"s"' +")'
        if (lvl == "2") {
            var cat = sessionStorage.getItem("cat");
            if (cat == "9f5fb2bc-c5b0-49d4-bb7d-c662ab91bd9d") {
                $("#direccion").html($("#direccion").html()+filterOutput);
            } else if (cat == "1b1c4e39-c642-42ad-b279-7ff5c9373c43") {
                $("#core").html($("#core").html()+filterOutput);
            } else if (cat == "a334da4e-1606-493b-8776-957c60d592f5") {
                $("#soporte").html($("#soporte").html()+filterOutput);
            }
        } else{
            currentFilter = $("#filter").html();
            $("#filter").html(currentFilter+filterOutput);
            if (hasParent != undefined && hasParent != 0) {
                $("#atras").show();
            };
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("lvl" + lvl + "_" + hasParent, filterOutput);
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", "lvl" + lvl + "_" + hasParent);
    }
}

function setBread (termName, lvl, GUID) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("bread", sessionStorage.getItem("bread") + termName + ",final...");
}

var fieldCollection;
var metaField = null;
var taxconfig = TaxConfiguration;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getMetaField, "SP.Taxonomy.js");

function getMetaField() {
    var lastLvl;
    $("#atras").hide();
    //Saca de la cookie el último grupo
    if(location.href.split('.aspx')[1]!=''){
        $("div[webpartid=608c8fe4-e5db-49de-8550-840b1706ba1c]").show();
        lastLvl = sessionStorage.getItem("lastLvl");
        var lastHtml = sessionStorage.getItem(lastLvl);
        $("#loadingOptions").hide();
        $("#mensaje").show();
        $("#maxFilter").show();
        if(lastLvl != "start") {
            $("#start").hide();
            $("#filter").html(lastHtml);
            $("#atras").show(); 
            $("#bread").show();
        }else {
            $("#bread").hide();
            $("#start").html(lastHtml);
            $("#start").show();
        }
        seeBread ();
    } else {
        var start = sessionStorage.getItem("start");
        if (start!=null) {
            $("#loadingOptions").hide();
            $("#filter").hide();
            $("#bread").hide();
            $("#bread").hide();
            $("#maxFilter").hide();
            $("#start").html(start);
            $("#start").show();
            sessionStorage.setItem("lvl", 2);   
            sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl","start");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("bread");
        }else{
            context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web(); 
            var site = context.get_site();
            var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
            fieldCollection = rootWeb.get_fields();
            metaField = fieldCollection.getByInternalNameOrTitle("SIG");
            context.load(fieldCollection);
            context.load(metaField);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed)
                );
        }
    }

}

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
    var fieldInfo = '';
    var fieldschema = metaField.get_schemaXml();
    taxconfig.Configuration = fieldschema;
    taxconfig.ParseConfiguration();
    try{
        var taxsspId = taxconfig.SspId;
        var termSetId = taxconfig.TermSetId;
        sessionStorage.setItem("lvl", 2);   
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl","start");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("bread");
        $("#atras").hide(); 
        $("#bread").hide(); 
        GetTermsRecursive(taxconfig.SspId, taxconfig.TermSetId);
        $("#start").show(); 
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }   
}

function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
    $("#filter").html('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Looks like quite the spaghetti code you have been left to maintain. I'm sure we will find ways to help you improve it!

Comment: thanks for the follow up!, it doesnt seem complex, for me was easy to understand, but still very slow. :(,

Comment: just received some info, the actual load times are not 5 minutes, its 15 seconds and its everywhere including old and modern laptops too. (firs time load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many design flaws here it would be hard to tell them all.
Worst is the lack of 'var' when using a variable in a function, which leads to global vars, which might result in horrific bugs. You should "use strict"; and track those issues.

To focus on your main issue, performance, you can get great results with minimal software risks by caching the results of the slowest operations : parsing xml and splitting strings.  In quite a few places, those operations are done again and again.

example 1 : simple caching increases both speed and readability of the `for` loop of `TaxConfiguration.ParseConfiguration`

```
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) { // Rq var was missing
     var thisProperty = properties[i];
     var firstChild   = thisProperty.firstChild ; 
     var lastChild    = thisProperty.lastChild  ; 
     propertyName     = firstChild.textContent || firstChild.text ;
     propertyValue    = lastChild.textContent  || lastChild.text  ; 
     if (propertyName == propertyValue) {
            propertyValue = "";
     }
     this[propertyName] = propertyValue;         
}
```

example 2 : avoid splitting many times in `seeBread`.  `irAtrasBread` can benefit from the same improvements.

```
function seeBread () {
    var output = "";   // much clearer here. 
    var bread = sessionStorage.getItem("bread");
    if (bread != null){
        var breadElements = bread.split("...");
        for(var i=0; i<breadElements.length-1;i++) {
            var thisBreadElementParts  = breadElements[i].split(","); 
            var onClick = " onclick='irAtrasBread(" +'"' thisBreadElementParts[1] + '"' + ", true)' "
            output += "<p class='separator'> > </p>"
            if (thisBreadElementParts[1] == "final") {
                output += "<span id='final'"+ onClick + ">" + thisBreadElementParts[0] + "</span>";
            } else {
                output += "<a "+ onClick + ">" + thisBreadElementParts[0] + "</a>";
            }
        };
    }
    var start = "'" + 'start' + "'";
    $("#bread").html('<p class="separator"> > </p><a href="#" onclick="irAtrasBread('+start + ',true)">Mapa de procesos</a>' + output);
}
```

3) In `GetChildTermsRecursive`, `sessionStorage.getItem("lvl")` should be cached.

4) Then caching the xml parsing might bring the more important improvements : example in `GetDataInit` (same can be done in `GetData` ).

```
function GetDataInit(xData, Status) 
{
    if(Status != "success") return;
    var xmlData = xData;        
    // Fix for different XML parsing in IE and Chrome
    var parsedResponseText = $.parseXML(xmlData.responseText) ;
    var termsContent = parsedResponseText.firstChild.textContent || parsedResponseText.text ; 
    var termsXML = $.parseXML(termsContent); // ??? 
    var $termsXML = $(termsXML);
    var childTerms = $termsXML.find("T");
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)  {
        var thisChildTerm = $(childTerms[j]);
        var termName = thisChildTerm.find("TL");
        var hasChildTermsXml = thisChildTerm.find("TM");
        // request if child terms are avaliable
        var hasChildTerms = $(hasChildTermsXml).attr("a69");
        // Requesting actual term id
        var tsTermId = thisChildTerm.attr("a9");    
        // Requestion term value ID
        var tsValueID = thisChildTerm.attr("a1000");
        // Requesting term name
        var tsTermName = termName.attr("a32");    
        sessionStorage.setItem("cat", tsTermId);
        GetChildTermsRecursive(sessionStorage.getItem("SspId"), sessionStorage.getItem("TermSetId"), tsTermId, tsTermName);
        sessionStorage.setItem("start", $("#start").html()); // once is enough
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastLvl", "start");
    }
}
```

Comment: on example 1, is this caching: this[propertyName] = propertyValue;   ???

Comment: no, it's just a shorter way to perform the assignment you do in your switch()

Comment: what did you change then on example 1? where is the caching?

Comment: properties[i].firstChild and properties[i].lastChild. You should see that everything is read only once (properties[i] and both children)